# Multiple loops in same page, without duplicate content

Tags: posts, loop, pages

I'm trying to make a page with multiple loops, I need every loop to display a predefined number of posts from the same category (every loop displays X number of posts from Category CATS). But I also need the second loop, the third loop and so on to display the posts from where the last loop stopped, without duplicating content (example: loop 1 from post 1 to 5. loop 2 from post 6 to 10. loop 3 from post 11 to 15 etc.). Here's what I've tried so far (I also gave a try to the code in the wordpress codex, but nothing seems to work)

Can you help me?

here's my code so far;

```
<?php   if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php   $mosaics = new WP_Query('category_name=mosaics&posts_per_page=5'); ?>
<?php   while ($mosaics->have_posts()) : $mosaics->the_post(); ?>
<?php   if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>

<?php   echo get_the_content(); ?>
<?php   endwhile; ?>
<?php   endif; ?>
<?php   wp_reset_query(); ?>

<br />

<?php   if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php   $mosaics = new WP_Query('category_name=mosaics&posts_per_page=4'); ?>
<?php   while ($mosaics->have_posts()) : $mosaics->the_post(); ?>
<?php   if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>

<?php   echo get_the_content(); ?>
<?php   endwhile; ?>
<?php   endif; ?>
<?php   wp_reset_query(); ?>

<br />

<?php   if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php   $mosaics = new WP_Query('category_name=mosaics&posts_per_page=3'); ?>
<?php   while ($mosaics->have_posts()) : $mosaics->the_post(); ?>
<?php   if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>

<?php   echo get_the_content(); ?>
<?php   endwhile; ?>
<?php   endif; ?>
<?php   wp_reset_query(); ?>

<br />

<?php   if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php   $mosaics = new WP_Query('category_name=mosaics&posts_per_page=2'); ?>
<?php   while ($mosaics->have_posts()) : $mosaics->the_post(); ?>
<?php   if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>

<?php   echo get_the_content(); ?>
<?php   endwhile; ?>
<?php   endif; ?>
<?php   wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: 'gave a try to the code in the wordpress codex' - are you referring to: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_in_Action

Comment: @Michael: yes, I tried that and other stuff but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is important to read this [Codex chapter](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_in_Action) all the way to the end, as the essential suggestions are after this heading **'Note for Multiple Posts in the First Category'**;

repetitive, tedious code:

```
<?php   $do_not_duplicate = array(); ?>
<?php   $mosaics = new WP_Query('category_name=mosaics&posts_per_page=5'); ?>
<?php   while ($mosaics->have_posts()) : $mosaics->the_post(); ?>
<?php   $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>

<?php   echo get_the_content(); ?>
<?php   endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<br />

<?php   $mosaics = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'mosaics', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate ) ); ?>
<?php   while ($mosaics->have_posts()) : $mosaics->the_post(); ?>
<?php   $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
<?php   echo get_the_content(); ?>
<?php   endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<br />

<?php   $mosaics = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'mosaics', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate ) ); ?>
<?php   while ($mosaics->have_posts()) : $mosaics->the_post(); ?>
<?php   $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
<?php   echo get_the_content(); ?>
<?php   endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<br />

<?php   $mosaics = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'mosaics', 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate ) ); ?>
<?php   while ($mosaics->have_posts()) : $mosaics->the_post(); ?>
<?php   $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
<?php   echo get_the_content(); ?>
<?php   endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

While Michael's answer works, doing multiple queries for this is a waste of database resources when you can get all of the results in a single query and handle breaking up output in PHP. See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71142/multiple-loops-homepage/71150#71150) I gave on another, similar question to achieve the same results with a single query to the database.

Comment: I totally agree; however, my answer is hopefully useful as a general layout on how to avoid duplicate posts with a multitude of loops.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `wp_reset_query()` after every query in order to clear the results of the previous queries, or create `WP_Query` instances where loops would be iterated through local variables instead of the global ones.

Comment: Nope, that alone would **not** prevent duplicate posts, because one post can have multiple categories.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Offset Parameter for the subsequent loops, this will start displaying posts after the number you specify:

```
// starts from post 6 to post 10
$mosaics = new WP_Query('category_name=mosaics&posts_per_page=5&offset=5');

// starts from post 11 to post 15
$mosaics = new WP_Query('category_name=mosaics&posts_per_page=5&offset=10');
```

Answer (score 0):

**The magic.**

```
 wp_reset_query();
```

That could be used to clean the way for further calls to WP_Query.
***Or*** to avoid the duplication due a non structured call to the loop, such:

```
$data = query_posts($args);
```