# How to show only the most recent post on my custom post type archive?

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, conditional-tags

I have registered a custom post type and inside my `archive-myCPT.php` I want to retrieve just the current published post.

Here is a relevant snippet from my `archive-myCPT.php`:

```
<?php 

    if( have_posts() ){
        $x = 1;
        while ( have_posts() ){
            the_post(); 
            if ( 0 === (int) $post->post_parent ) {
                get_template_part( 'inc/post-format/content-debate');
            }
```

I've tried adding this : `query_posts('posts_per_page=1&order=DESC&orderby=date')` before the
`if( have_posts() ){` but I'm getting the last post from the default blog posts not from my CPT and also it adds also a pagination.

How can I retrieve **just** the most recent published post inside my CPT without the pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just alter the main query for your custom post type archive with [pre_get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

**Code:**

```
function wpse124228_alter_ppp_order_for_mycpt( $query ) {
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || is_admin() )
        return;
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'mycpt' ) ) {
        //Only display 1 post on mycpt archive
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
        //Most recent/current
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse124228_alter_ppp_order_for_mycpt' );
```

This pretty much resembles this [example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Changing_the_number_of_posts_per_page.2C_by_post_type) from the codex page. BTW **don't** use `query_posts()`, if you have to do a second query go with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), but for an archive that shouldn't be necessary.

**Additional Information:**

- [Template_Hierarchy: Custom_Post_Types_display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display)
- [Post_Types: Custom_Post_Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types)
- [Custom Post Type Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates)
- [How to Create a Custom Post Types Archive Page in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-post-types-archive-page-in-wordpress/)

Comment: What about if I have to retrieve also inside my `archive-CPT.php` the most recent post with the status of `future` and the last published post ?

Comment: This would be a totally different question. BTW how can a future post be most recent, I guess you mean the next to come. But this *really* should be a new question, because it's a new problem. @Alecs

Comment: Sorry, I meant the next to come ...

Comment: I've added a question regardin this [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124047/custom-post-type-upcoming-post-and-past-post)

Comment: Not a problem, can you check mark the answer to resolve the process. I'll take a look at your other question. @Alecs