# WP_query to get the first two latest posts, then another loop to get the next three

Tags: wp-query

My ultimate goal is to list the latest 5 posts, regardless of category.

I would first like to make a `WP_Query` to get the latest two posts and insert them in to a specific HTML structure.

Then I would like to make another `WP_Query` to get the next three posts and insert them in to a differing HTML structure.

I've tried a few code snippets and what happens is each `WP_Query` starts from the latest post in both HTML structures. Is there an arg that I can use to specifically tell the second query to skip the first two posts?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/138093/how-to-display-most-recent-posts-that-havent-already-been-displayed-with-wp-que

Comment: Also in my opinion you can do it with one query.

Answer (score 7):

Run one wp_query for post_per_page = 2 and get the IDs of these 2 posts in an array to be excluded in the next 3 posts needed

```
<?php

    // The Query
    $next_args = array(
                    'post_type' => '<your_post_type>',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page'=>2,
                    'order'=>'DESC',
                    'orderby'=>'ID',
                    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $not_in_next_three = array();
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            //your html here for latest 2
            $not_in_next_three[] = get_the_ID();
        }

    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Now the array created above to be excluded in the wp_query fetching the next 3 posts

```
// The Query
$next_args = array(
                'post_type' => '<your_post_type>',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page'=>3,
                'order'=>'DESC',
                'orderby'=>'ID',
                'post__not_in'=>$not_in_next_three
                );
$next_the_query = new WP_Query( $next_args );

// The Loop
if ( $next_the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $next_the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $next_the_query->the_post();
        //your html here fir latest next 3

    }

} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Comment: Add some explanation to yor code and method you are using. This can clearly be done in one query, not 2

Comment: Yeah can be done in one query .. but the question owner has asked for 2 wp_query .. that is why...

Comment: check the edited answer now @peiter Goosen

Comment: I solved this problem by performing two WP_Query on the same page and using an offset parameter in the second set of args. 

I'd like to know how to use one query and achieve the same result.

Comment: It can be done in one wp_query by increasing counter and changing the HTML structure on basis of counter .

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`WP_Query`'s pagination paramters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

However, using two queries to accomplish this objective is inefficient. A better solution it to use one query and alter your markup based on the value of [`WP_Query`'s `$current_post` property](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods_and_Properties), which (when used in the loop) reflects the index of the post currently being processed within the current page of results.