# Category page shows only 1 post when that post has more than 1 category?

Tags: categories, loop

The error I'm seeing is that the way I currently have my category page set up, if a post on that page has more than 1 category, the loop won't load the posts that follow the one with multiple categories.

Currently I have about 10 posts in my test installation of WordPress. 9 of them have the same category, lets call it "Surprised". 1 of them has 3 categories. When I go to the category for page "Surprised, instead of seeing 10 posts on that page, including the one with 3 different categories, the page stops loading the category posts that follow it.

Here is an example of one of the loops that ate on the category page (there are 4 loops total and all of them behave the same presently).

```
<? get_header(); ?>

<?
$cat_array = get_the_category();
$cat_name = esc_html($cat_array[0]->name);
?>
    <?
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args  = array(
      'category_name'  => $cat_name,
      'paged'          => $paged,
      'posts_per_page' => 2
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post-box pane">
      <a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>" class="article">
        <h3 class="title"><? echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
        <? echo the_post_thumbnail('smaller-general-thumb', array('class' => 'thumb')) ?>
      </a>
    </div>
    <? endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

The reason I'm doing 4 sections with different loops is because each section has a specific number of posts in it. I have to limit the number of posts that show for a section, so I create a new loop and I limit the posts for that loop by paging them and limiting posts per page.

Comment: Category archives do not need to `get_the_category()` again. Simply do a simple WP Loop (the loop), here you can see: https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/archive.php

Comment: what if I have 4 loops on that page that need to be offset? Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: You are doing it all wrong if you have 4 loops on your category archive page. You are going to have an endless amount of crap, gaurenteed ;-)

Comment: Unless you're offering me a solution, you're response doesn't really help me much  @PieterGoosen

Comment: Without knowing *why* you are doing it, and why you are breaking the main query, that is a much as I can comment. File an [edit] and explain what you are trying to do

Comment: @PieterGoosen Ok I updated my question.

Comment: if you are running multiple loops to divide the page into sections, see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71150/4771) for splitting a single query among multiple sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Multiple Loops

Outside the loop you can get available terms of the core taxonomy *category* with [`get_terms( 'taxonomy_name' )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms). The resulting array contains objects like

```
object(stdClass)#141 (9) {
    ["term_id"] => string(1) "3"
    ["name"] => string(9) "The Name of your Category"
    ["slug"] => string(9) "name-of-tax-term"
    ["term_group"] => string(1) "0"
    ["term_taxonomy_id"] => string(1) "3"
    ["taxonomy"] => string(11) "slug_of_tax"
    ["description"] => string(41) "Description of Term."
    ["parent"] => string(1) "0"
    ["count"] => string(1) "3"
}
```

So you would want to get the category slug, not its name:

```
$cats = get_terms( 'category' );
```

You could then loop the categories like

```
foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
    $args  = array(
      'category_name'  => $cat->slug,
      'paged'          => $paged,
      'posts_per_page' => 2
    );
    // the loop
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

#### One Loop

If your loop runs on the unchanged main query, the current category is already present in the query.

Just change

```
$args  = array(
  'category_name'  => $cat_name,
  'paged'          => $paged,
  'posts_per_page' => 2
);
```

to

```
$args  = array(
  'paged'          => $paged,
  'posts_per_page' => 2
);
```

in your code.

Besides, when not using [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) inside the loop, you have to pass a post ID as argument.

Comment: I think I should be using the unchanged main query, but now, the category pages seem to run their loops like the index loop... just listing the posts from more recent to older.

Comment: updated my answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution I found to be the most elegant and appropriate for my situation:

```
<? global $wp_query; ?>

$args  = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'posts_per_page' => 2));
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

/// The loop

<? endwhile; rewind_posts(); ?>
```

I specifically decided to use array_merge in order to merge the global query with the loop I'm writing in order to limit the number of posts for that loop. Now I don't need to specify the category since that's already in the global query. No need to update dat bish myself.

Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: negative 1 for what reason? Don't down vote without proper feedback. At least in the future I can correct myself.

Comment: This is an even worst solution than your actual problem. @Milo has linked to a post which will solve your issue, no idea why you do not want to use it. Using `query_posts` is really really bad, and running it 5 times is 5 times worst. If you are after SEO and page rankings, you will never reach top 1000 as `query_posts` slows your page down dramatically, and using it 5 times adds up to even slower page loads. Consider using the solution that @Milo have given you

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I didn't know that. If it works I'm more than happy to give him credit.

Comment: I updated my answer with a more performant version of what I had.

Comment: Why are you still running custom queries. It still makes no sense running custom queries. Your question also still does not really explain why

Comment: I guess it's logical that I'd be trying use the same list of posts for the category and spread them across the entire page. I'm not trying to do that. I'm repeating the query again and again in different sections, except limiting the number of posts each time. So his answer makes sense if that's what I were trying to do. Now, why would I want to do what I'm doing? Because the sections will change later and this is a placeholder. I don't yet know exactly what I want the other sections to display.

Comment: *I don't yet know exactly what I want the other sections to display*. IMHO, your lack of desicion at this stage makes it really impossible to answer you directly. Even with this new updated answer, it is still really bad for SEO and page speed. The global main query objec is there, it is just a matter of using it correctly ;-)